# Proper DB design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently working on a project that contains many different tables that use normalization to effectively minimize duplication and NULL cell values. My question pertains on the proper approach to minimizing the amount of tables being utilized and whether or not the approach I am going is bad and the approach I might go has foreseeable problems.

I quickly drew up an example comparable to what I am doing but far more simplified.

Please help my understand which approach is better, or is there a better one then shown?

[Image http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6972/helpdb.jpg](http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6972/helpdb.jpg)

The link to the larger image, http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/6972/helpdb.jpg

Edit: I would like to thank everyone for the overwhelming great answers / comments.
I was able to cut my initial data structure tables by roughly 40%; the answers also helped me refine my current data structure, making it far more expansible. I hope to finish this project within the next 2-3 months. Then you can take a look at what you helped me learn and build! Thank you so much and I look to forward contributing to the community where I can now and more as I grow in my knowledge and experience. Thank you again!

Comment: None of the 2 approaches is good. You can do what you need with 2 tables. 1 for entities where you put people, dogs and fishes together and separate them by `type_id` or similar column and then you have `entity_illness_resilience` table, you link it up via `entity`.`id` = `entity_illness_resilience`.`entity_id`

Comment: Mmm, I would like to do that but say person id contains "first name, last name, date of birth, death, favorie color, etc.."   a fish does not have any of those attributes and thus would create many NULL cell values for those columns if I compiled all "creatures" into a universal entities table.  I understand I did not declare that in my question, however the current table structure is quite extensive and I was attempting to isolate a problem with out adding all the relations

Comment: Actually I take that back, it still may work. Just having the person / fish / dog table reference the entities ID instead of the other way around. Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: I'm sorry, still sorta new to how things work here. I'll do that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've always enjoyed the practice of showing inheritance in datamodels, and I think you have the right idea with Approach 2, because you are trying to treat similar entities in a similar fashion.  However, I agree that the two null values is ugly and incorrect.  Here is how I would model your data:

```
ENTITY
entity_id PK
entity_type

PERSON
entity_id PK FK REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
name

DOG
entity_id PK FK REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
name

FISH
entity_id PK FK REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
name
```

What we have here is an "abstract" table entity, and three "concrete" tables (using object-oriented programming lingo here).  The concrete tables share their primary key with the primary key of the ENTITY table, saying that a given record IS that entity, and since entities have illnesses, the person/dog/fish has that illness as well.

The "entity_type" column on ENTITY says what table the record is from (maybe an ENUM("P", "D", or "F"), or spell out the whole names).  This is more a convenience in case you need to go from the ENTITY table down to the concrete tables, but obviously isn't required when going from the concrete tables to ENTITY.

This datamodel maps nicely to web applications using Hibernate and an object model that accurately describes the inheritance relationships.  I've implemented this type of solution many times with great success.

**EDIT**

What is nice about this approach over the approach of some previous answers that use "entity_type" and a single table, is that this model let's you attach data specific to the concrete tables - not only on the table itself, but relationships even.

So for example, let's say:

- All DOGs and FISHes have a PERSON owner
- PERSON has a race
- DOGs and FISHes have a species

Your schema could look like this:

```
ENTITY
entity_id PK
name
entity_type

PERSON
entity_id PK FK REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
race_id FK REFERENCES RACE(race_id)

DOG
entity_id PK FK REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
owner_id FK REFERENCES PERSON(entity_id)
species

FISH
entity_id PK FK REFERENCES ENTITY(entity_id)
owner_id FK REFERENCES PERSON(entity_id)
species
```

Note that as Alix pointed out, you can definitely move the `name` to the super table, since it is common across all entities.

Comment: Ok I think I see what I can do, make entities table a master table containing all the entities and then have the individual entity specific tables reference that table. I'll have to relook at my DB layout. If any of you are wanting to look at my current 91 table structure and see if it could be optimized better, let me know. :)

Comment: One problem here comes when coding a query that wants to deal with all entity types.  You end up UNIONing all the concrete tables back together.

Comment: Best answer so far, but with the described schema there is no need to have the `person`, `dog` and `fish` tables as they should only add value to describe data that isn't common to `entity`.

Answer (score 5):

Why even have separate tables for different entity types? You could do it like this:

Entity: id_entity , name, entity_type (ie person,dog,fish,etc)

Illness_resilience: entity_id, illness_id, etc...

Comment: Maybe because different entities could have different attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is better than the first one, however I would suggest a little modification:

#### entities

- id_entity
- id_animal
- animal_type (enum = person, dog, fish)

You get the idea, also, be sure to check the following links:

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html
- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html
- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html

Comment: I think there's an argument to be made for having another table that contains all possible animal types and using a FK instead of an enum. In that case you can expand the list of possible animals using an INSERT instead of an ALTER.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use a SuperType/SubType Structure

The first question you need to ask is this... Will the entities (People, Dogs, Fish) ever share the same illness_resillience. If the answer is no, then there's no need to create a 1 to many relationship between entity and illness_resillience.

If the answer to the above is no then you have a 1 to 1 relationahip between entity and illness_resillience. Now, you can create what is called a **Supertype/Subtype** data structure. The **SuperType** contains all the elements that are common and the **SubType** contains all the elements that are unique.

In the example you cited, the entity table would include everything that is common between People, Dogs, Fish and any other entity you add later. Then you create a separate table for each SubType that links back to the SuperType table.

```
[tableEntity]
EntityId,
EntityTypeId,
Name,
Weight,
LifeExpectancy,
Etc

[tablePeople]     [tableDogs]     [tableFish]
PeopleId,         DogId,          FishId,
EntityTypeId,     EntityTypeId,   EntityTypeId,
UniquePeople1,    UniqueDog1,     UniqueFish1,
UniquePeople2,    UniqueDog2,     UniqueFish2
UniquePeople3,    UniqueDog3,     UniqueFish3
Etc...            Etc...          Etc...
```

You create seperate joins between the SuperType table and the SubType tables to get the total information for each relationship:

```
Join Entity to People on EntityTypeId for EntityPeople
Join Entity to Dogs   on EntityTypeId for EntityDogs
Join Entity to Fish   on EntityTypeId for EntityFish
```

Answer (score 0):

Design-wise, I think approach 2 is bad because it doesn't allow future extensions of the design (e.g. add more creatures) without changing existing structures. Maybe that's an issue for you, maybe not. Also, approach 1 is bad, because changes to the resilience table have to be done for each resilience table.

I'd prefer to have a `resilience` table and one relationship table *for each* creature type that relates the creature table with the resilience table.

Maybe it's also beneficial to introduce a `creature_type` table to answer specific questions about the resilience of specific creature types. The resilience table would reference this table.

**UPDATE**

You can also have a single **relationship table** with the `creature_id` and the `creature_type`. Even though you won't be able to set a foreign key for the `creature_id`, I have seem this being used in practice to great effect. It also makes the design more flexible.

Comment: That is what I feel is best, however in my project that may mean creating upwards of an additional 60 tables, it seems like a lot for someone as inexperienced as me. But maybe that is just the norm for comprehensive database projects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your structure is that entities *could* have more than one of the entity types enabled.

I'd recommend that this would be a better approach...

People: personId, illnessId, name

Fish: fishId, illnessId, name

Dogs: dogId, illnessId, name

Comment: Person will be referenced in many different tables one area of which in this hypothetical situation is their illness resilience. Not to mention not all persons will have an illness, thus the reason for a relation table. Also what if the person has multiple illness, I have to use a separate relation table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the correct approach with #2,  perhaps your entities table could contain a entity type ENUM('Person','Dog','Cat') and a single id column.  Though that wouldn't take too kindly to foreign keys.

You don't want to design this thing so you have to create a new resilience table every time you add a new entity.  And if you have specific attribute to apply to only one type of entity it can be stored in persons,dogs,cats tables.

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating fields and values in separate tables both for illnesses and people, dogs, fish. You will have to write different insert, update and delete statements for each new table. That's alot of overhead.

Approach two is better but it too will have lots of added inserts/updates due to the people, dogs, fish being in separate tables. Those shared attributes should be consolidated in one table and the additional attributes could be in separate tables.

However, if the people, dogs, fish etc are already defined and something you must live with then

**Variation on your #2**

Instead of having the keys on the person, fish, etc.  Have the key be on entity and have the Foreign key be to the person, fish etc. It eliminates the nulls your looking at.  Think that you have to have an entity before you can have a person, fish etc.. as those are attributes of the entity  So the Entity_id is never repeated, and is unique across ALL people, fish, dogs etc... IT eliminates the need for PK on People, dogs etc, or they can be retained and entity_ID simply becomes a FK to those tables

Alternatively, if the schema is not already locked in, you can do this and offer flexibility in any direction.

**6 Tables scale-able to any size casting**

It eliminates the null problem you asked for and requires no structure changes when new fish, or person attributes are discovered.  Nor structure changes when a new entity is added "Cats" for example.  however comes with a cost of performance loss on data type casting  and a lot more coding; but once done, little additional maintenance effort required (other than changing data; but no code!)

CONs:

1. Much harder to conceptualize / Do
2. SQL can be difficult to write
3. When new attributes are added can cause problems with existing records if not taken into account when initially written.
4. You have to write dynamic controls to and iterate though all the attributes to be truly data driven at run time.

PROs:

- Scale to any number of entities
- Hold any number of dog, cat, or fish attributes
- Eliminates all NULL issues you indicated
- Very OO esque  you create a collection of attributes for the entity data instead of having a row...

**Entity_Type** *(Person, fish, dog, etc.. ITs data it can grow to any size)*

- Entity_Type_ID (PK)
- Entity_Type_name (string)

**Entity** *(a specific person, fish, dog etc)*

- Entity_ID (PK)
- Entity_Type_ID (FK to Entity_Type)
- Entity_Name (String)
- any other fields which are common to ALL entity_Types (now and in the future or you have nulls)

**Attribute_Type** complete list of available attributes for any entity_type

- Attribute_Type_ID (PK)
- Attribute_Name (String)
- Attribute_Data_Type (For casting purposes) (string, date, number, etc)
- isRequired (bit)

**Entity_Attribute_Types**  *(Defines what attributes are are available for a specific entity)*

- Attribute_Type_ID (FK) (Combine FK's to make Unique Key)
- Entity_Type_ID (FK)

**Entity_Attribute** *(Stores the value user provided for the attribute entered)*

- Entity_ID (FK)  (Combine FKs to make Unique Key)
- Attribute_Type_Id (FK)
- Value (String)

**Entity_Illness_Resilience**

- Entity_ID (FK) (Combine FKs to make unique Key)
- Illness_ID (FK)
- your other fields

Entity_Attribute table basically holds **ALL** the entity attribute data except for those that are common to all entities and the other associated data (illness_resilience, etc)